# Is there any free api for currency converter, with maximum number of supported currency and unlimited api calls?

Tags: android, api, currency

I have been trying to make an currency converter app, The app is almost complete. 
As of now I am using [fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) for currency rates, but it seems it does not supports many currency and hence crashes my app everytime there is no specified currency.

I even tried using [google currency converter](https://www.google.com/finance/converter). It seems they are not providing any api for this. Hence, I tried working around with their results on above link. Results are in HTML tags, but this tags only have the select value options and not the result which is shown in span tag, check page source for this.

I have put in about 3 weeks of hardwork into this, don't want to lose at this point now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://fincharts.info

Answer (score 4):

You may check out https://free.currencyconverterapi.com

Disclaimer though, I'm the author.

A sample conversion URL is: http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=PHP_USD&compact=ultra&apiKey=sample-api-key which will return a value in json format, e.g. {"PHP_USD":0.019433}

Comment: It is NOT free anymore. Free is only for testing/demo use. If you request more then it will return 400 and give you an error:  
```"The system has detected this request as an abuse of the free service. If you need more requests, please consider using the paid service. Please check currencyconverterapi.com/pricing for more information. Thank you."```  
and also block your ip and api-key.

Comment: Even the demo on their free page doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround would be to download currency rates from [European Central Bank](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html) and convert the feed and use it locally

Answer (score 1):

Get currency data from google using URL

https://www.google.com/search?q=inr+to+usd&oq=INR+to+USD
and write code to use that data accordingly.

I have deployed one service on heroku, below is the link
https://api-currency-converter.herokuapp.com/api/convert?from=USD&to=INR

Git Repo : https://github.com/msdhillon8989/currencyConverter